# Change the values being operated on in lapply to create a matrix from a list

Tags: r

I am running the following code in r to transform correlations I have extracted in wide format (dat7) into a list of correlation matrices.

(The code is my attempt to reimplement http://www.suzannejak.nl/MASEM_functions.R)

```
Article <- c("Matrix_1","Matrix_2","Matrix_3","Matrix_4")
n.tot <- c(100,101,102,103)
Corr.A.B <- c(0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6)
Corr.B.C <- c(0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2)
Corr.A.C <- c(0.1,0.0,-0.1,-0.2)
Corr.A.D <- c(-0.3,-0.4,-0.5,-0.6)
Corr.B.D <- c(-0.7,-0.8,-0.9,0.9)
Corr.C.D <- c(0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5)

dat7 <- data.frame(Article, 
                   n.tot, 
                   Corr.A.B, 
                   Corr.B.C, 
                   Corr.A.C,
                   Corr.A.D,
                   Corr.B.D,
                   Corr.C.D)

no.var <- 4

my.df <- as.matrix(dat7)
no.groups <- nrow(my.df)
no.col <- ncol(my.df)
my.list <- split(my.df, 1:no.groups)
  
my.mat <- lapply(my.list, 
                 function(x, no.var) {
                   mat <- matrix(0, ncol = no.var, nrow = no.var)
                   mat[lower.tri(mat, diag = FALSE)] <- x
                   mat
                   },
                 no.var)
```

The output of my.list is correct:

```
> my.list
$`1`
[1] "Matrix_1" "100"      "0.9"      "0.5"      " 0.1"     "-0.3"     "-0.7"    
[8] "0.8"
```

The (truncated) output I get from calling my.mat:

```
> my.mat
$`1`
     [,1]       [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,] "0"        "0"    "0"    "0" 
[2,] "Matrix_1" "0"    "0"    "0" 
[3,] "100"      "0.5"  "0"    "0" 
[4,] "0.9"      " 0.1" "-0.3" "0"
```

Along with the error:

```
Warning: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The error makes sense to me, I am asking lapply to iterate over eight items in my.list but there are only six places in the generated matrix to put values into.

What I want:

```
> my.mat
$`1`
     [,1]       [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,] "0"        "0"    "0"    "0" 
[2,] "0.9"      "0"    "0"    "0" 
[3,] "0.5"      "0.1"  "0"    "0" 
[4,] "-0.3"     "-0.7" "0.8"  "0"
```

How can I tell the lapply function to exclude the first two items from my.list when passing the values to the matrix function?

(i.e. iterate over `"0.9" "0.5" " 0.1" "-0.3" "-0.7" "0.8"` instead of  `"Matrix_1" "100" "0.9" "0.5" "0.1" "-0.3" "-0.7" "0.8"`?)

Comment: 1. This is off-topic here. 2. Never turn a data.frame that contains mixed data types into a matrix.

Comment: 1. Cheers, I've asked for it to be moved to SO. 2. I only want the numeric data to become part of the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to drop the unnecessary columns from the data frame before converting it to a matrix and processing it further.

```
#my.df <- as.matrix(dat7)  #don't turn the data frame into a matrix 
no.groups <- nrow(my.df)
no.col <- ncol(my.df)

my.df.shortened <- my.df[3:no.col]  #Drop the first two columns
my.df.shortened <- as.matrix.data.frame(my.df.shortened)   
my.list <- split(my.df.shortened, 1:no.groups)             
  
my.mat <- lapply(my.list, 
                 function(x, no.var) {
                   mat <- matrix(0, ncol = no.var, nrow = no.var)
                   mat[lower.tri(mat, diag = FALSE)] <- x
                   mat
                   },
                 no.var)
```

gave me:

```
> my.mat
$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  1.0  0.9  0.5  0.1
[2,]  0.9  1.0 -0.3 -0.7
[3,]  0.5 -0.3  1.0  0.8
[4,]  0.1 -0.7  0.8  1.0
```